# Populate ComboBox with line styles .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+

How could I populate a ComboBox (or a ToolStripComboBox like in the image) with line styles .NET?

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S9ASrI4TE8I/AAAAAAAADKo/pNzm6MVyYkA/s800/linestyles.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S9ASrI4TE8I/AAAAAAAADKo/pNzm6MVyYkA/s800/linestyles.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw the items yourself. The ComboBox has a [`DrawItem` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem.aspx) for that. You can get both the boundaries of the item and the graphics context from the event arguments.

You'll need to set the [DrawMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode.aspx) on the ComboBox to OwnerDrawFixed for that to work, though.

I'm assuming that finding the [DashStyle enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.dashstyle.aspx) and creating an item for each enum value is not your problem here.

Comment: Thanks. Did't tryed, however, but after some reflections reformulated in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690044/display-colorpicker-net